# Where are the sources of sun.reflect?

Tags: java, reflection

While debugging Java code that uses reflection in Eclipse, some times I need to step into my invoked method or constructor. But reflection classes such as `java.lang.reflect.Method` and `java.lang.Class` do internal calls to `sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl`, `sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl`, `sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory` and others. These classes are not in the src.zip that is shipped with JDK.

This requires me to add `sun.reflect.*` to the debugger Step Filters. Otherwise I would have to press F5 (Step Into) multiple times in bytecode view, without any clue of when it will get into my code.

But being a curious person, I wish to know what's going on. Someone please can tell from where can I download those sources, if such a link or repository exists?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/reflect/

Comment: @Mob: that will only apply if @fernacolo is running a project with the OpenJDK. From my understanding, the contents of the `sun.*` packages are intended to be implementation-specific and/or closed-source, and therefore, you won't necessarily have access to an official version of the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html):

#### Java SE 6 JDK Source Code

JDK 6 source code is available for those interested in exploring the details of the JDK. This includes schools, universities, companies, and individuals who want to examine the source code for personal interest or research & development. The licensing does not impose restrictions upon those who wish to work on independent open-source projects.

http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/

---

and OpenJDK source jars are [here](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/)

Comment: The link is not existent anymore